# Server.MapPath(~) alternative

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC application and I want to get the remote address to access a certain file.

In my img tags, I'm using `~/`

As of `<img src="~/Content/img/logo.svg"/>`

In this case, the tilde will be interpreted.

But I want to create the tags via javascript, like this:

```
var $state = $(
  '<span><img src="~/Content/img/bancos/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-banco" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
);
```

The tilde won't be interpreted in this case.

What alternative can I use?

I have tried this:

```
var $state = $(
  '<span><img src="@Server.MapPath(~)/Content/img/bancos/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="img-banco" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
);
```

But this will return the application folder in the server, like `E:\inetpub\...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about `@Href` and it worked as expected!

```
var $state = $(
    '<span><img src="@Href("~/Content/img/bancos/")' + padder.pad(state.element.value) + '.png" class="img-banco" /> &nbsp; ' + state.text + '</span>'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Server.MapPath` returns the path to the physical directory. You need a relative url to your app root (or to your image)

You should generate the value to the root in a razor view using the helper method(s) and store that in a js variable and use that. Always **use javascript namespacing** to avoid global variable value overwriting scenarios

So in your layout file or view

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};  
    myApp.Urls = myApp.Urls || {};
    myApp.Urls.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';        
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js"></script>
```

And in your external javascript(`PageSpecificExternalJsFile.js`) file, you can read it like.

```
var imageLocation= myApp.Urls.baseUrl+'Content/img/bancos/hi.jpg';
// use this imageLocation now
```

Comment: Upon debug, I got this: `myApp.Urls.baseUrl = "/"`

Comment: Yes. That is the app root( relative path). Your js code should work for the current page. Just use that as the base url and append your remaining part

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is:

```
src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/img/bancos/{0}.png", state.element.value.toLowerCase()))"
```

I don´t know if it applies directly to your code but I believe that @Url.Content will get you there.

Regards,